# Does All The Functions From A Group To The Complex Numbers Is A Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Lets there be a group $X$

$\mathbb{C}^x$ is all the functions $X \rightarrow \mathbb{C} $

Addition is defined $f(x)+g(x)=(f+g)(x)$ and scalar multiplication is defined $(\alpha*f)(x)=\alpha*f(x)$

Above which field $\mathbb{C},\mathbb{R},\mathbb{Q}$ does $\mathbb{C}^x$ a vector space?

Because the addition of functions are closed the only thing left to test is scalar multiplication and I do not see any reason why it may not be closed under all $\mathbb{C},\mathbb{R},\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: You are right. There is  a wide variety of fields $F$ such that $\mathbb{C}^X$ can be viewed as a vector space over $F$.

Comment: Also note that the group structure on $X$ is not needed at all. In fact, $X$ could be any (probably nonempty) set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove for yourself that, if $F\subseteq K$ is a field extension, that any $K$ vector space is also an $F$ vector space.

It won't always be true that an $F$ vector space is a $K$ vector space, though. Just consider $\Bbb Q$ as a vector space over itself, and ask if it could be a $\Bbb R$ vector space.

In your case, it suffices to show that the functions are a $\Bbb C$ vector space, and it is true for all subfields of $\Bbb C$ as well.

Comment: if the a vector space is from a field and the scalar are from a bigger field, for example $\mathbb{Q}$ over $\mathbb{R}$ than it is not closed for scalar multiplication